# XML Python parsing for creating database

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to create a database using python on my xml file. I'm closed to the output I wish.

First, here is my Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<SoccerFeed TimeStamp="20180518T155346+0100">
 -<SoccerDocument uID="f920535" detail_id="1" Type="Result">
  +<Competition uID="c24">
  -<MatchData>
   +<MatchInfo TimeStamp="20170805T180614+0100" Period="FullTime" 
    MatchType="Regular">
   -<MatchOfficial uID="o41564">
    +<OfficialData>
    +<OfficialName>
    </MatchOfficial>
   +<AssistantOfficials>
    <Stat Type="match_time">95</Stat>
    <Stat Type="first_half_start">20170805T161515+0100</Stat>
    <Stat Type="first_half_time">46</Stat>
    <Stat Type="first_half_stop">20170805T170023+0100</Stat>
    <Stat Type="second_half_start">20170805T171702+0100</Stat>
    <Stat Type="second_half_time">50</Stat>
    <Stat Type="second_half_stop">20170805T180614+0100</Stat>
   -<TeamData TeamRef="t149" Side="Home" Score="2">
     -<Goal TimeStamp="20170805T165633+0100" uID="g149-1" Type="Goal" 
  Period="FirstHalf" Time="42" Sec="18" PlayerRef="p40720" Min="41" 
      EventNumber="1421" EventID="1618948311">
         <Assist PlayerRef="p15780">p15780</Assist>
      </Goal>
     +<Goal TimeStamp="20170805T175201+0100" uID="g149-2" Type="Goal" 
     Period="SecondHalf" Time="80" Sec="58" PlayerRef="p54782" Min="79" 
     EventNumber="2802" EventID="1632402633">
     -<PlayerLineUp>
       -<MatchPlayer PlayerRef="p84182" Status="Start" ShirtNumber="16" 
     Position="Goalkeeper">
        <Stat Type="leftside_pass">7</Stat>
        <Stat Type="accurate_keeper_sweeper">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="accurate_pass">30</Stat>
        <Stat Type="rightside_pass">11</Stat>
        <Stat Type="attempts_conceded_ibox">3</Stat>
        <Stat Type="touches">44</Stat>
        <Stat Type="total_fwd_zone_pass">2</Stat>
        <Stat Type="keeper_pick_up">6</Stat>
        </MatchPlayer>
       -<MatchPlayer PlayerRef="p116406" Status="Start" ShirtNumber="5" 
     Position="Defender">
        <Stat Type="duel_lost">2</Stat>
        <Stat Type="blocked_scoring_att">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="leftside_pass">34</Stat>
        <Stat Type="att_rf_total">2</Stat>
        <Stat Type="att_bx_right">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="accurate_pass">69</Stat>
        <Stat Type="att_miss_left">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="total_final_third_passes">2</Stat>
        </MatchPlayer>
       -<MatchPlayer PlayerRef="p15780" Status="Start" ShirtNumber="32" 
      Position="Defender">
        <Stat Type="total_through_ball">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="duel_lost">4</Stat>
        <Stat Type="blocked_scoring_att">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="leftside_pass">46</Stat>
        <Stat Type="dispossessed">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="accurate_cross">2</Stat>
        <Stat Type="att_rf_total">1</Stat>
        </MatchPlayer>
```

I would like to get the Id of the player ("PlayerRef"), his "ShirtNumber", his "Position", the "Type of the statistic" and the "Statistic" itself.

For now, what I have done  is close to the output expected, but I still got an error that I can't fix.
Here my python code :

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree

file_name="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/BYG/PSG-Amiens.xml"
full_file=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('BYG',file_name))
dom=ElementTree.parse(full_file)

Stats=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineUp/MatchPlayer')
Type=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineUp/MatchPlayer/Stat')


for s in Stats:
    ID=s.get('PlayerRef')
    Position=s.get('Position')
    Shirt=s.get('ShirtNumber')
        for t in Type:
        Types=t.get('Type')
        Reponse=t.text
        print(' * {} [{}] {} - {}  {}'.format(ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Reponse))
```

When I run this code, it compiles all the type of statistics and the statistics of every players for just one player when it should be just the type of statistics of the player concerned and his statistics, not the one from all others players.

To be more clear, For the player 1 I should get just the ID, the ShirtNumber, 
the Position, All the type of Statistics and the statistics for the player 1.

But instead I get his ID, ShirtNumber,Position and All the type of Statistics and the statistics present in my xml file.

How could I fix that?

I hope I have been clear enough, don't hesitate to ask me more precisions if I haven't been clear enough

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are iterating through all 'MatchPlayer/Stat' elements. You should narrow your search to only get the stats of the player you are working with.

Comment: Unrelated, but do those `+` and `-` really appear in your XML?

Comment: @usr2564301 It appears on my XML interpreter, but not on a url file

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the specific individual player statistics while iterating through the player stats.

```
for s in Stats:
    ID=s.get('PlayerRef')
    Position=s.get('Position')
    Shirt=s.get('ShirtNumber')
    Type=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineU/MatchPlayer[@PlayerRef={0}]/Stat'.format(ID))

        for t in Type:
            Types=t.get('Type')
            Reponse=t.text
            print(' * {} [{}] {} - {} {}'.format(ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Reponse))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with running your code I get a KeyError:
`KeyError: ('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineU/MatchPlayer[@PlayerRef={0}]/Stat', None)`
And some others errors:
  `File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 697, in findall
    return self._root.findall(path, namespaces)
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: invalid predicate`